# How to Start and Stop Cloudera Cluster CD5 Using Command Line or Shell Script

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I have installed Cloudera Cluster on AWS EC2 instances.
Easily I can start or stop it using cloudera manager.
But now I want to make a shell script that can start or stop it.

What is the command line to start and stop the cluster and all its services?

Comment: I tried figuring it out for you but it sounds like they want you to use the REST API but that sounds really terrible so hopefully there is a better way! http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v11/index.html .. they have some suggestions on how to do it with CDH but since you are using the Manager they say to not use those commands too.

Comment: Can you give me example of it?

Comment: I don't know enough to help you but according to the link it looks like you would call the API with something like this: `/clusters/{clusterName}/commands/start` and this `/clusters/{clusterName}/commands/stop` ... so I believe you would do something like this `curl -u myusername:mypassword http://somesite.com/clusters/{clusterName}/commands/stop` from the command line to accomplish what you want.  I don't have Cloudera installed so can't test it but if that works for you I'll post it as an answer to your question.